# Подсчет количетва изменений поля в таблице

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица в БД MySQL(5.6.40) вида:

```
| id | alias |  time | status |
| 1  | test1 | 10:25 |    1   |
| 2  | test2 | 10:26 |    1   |
| 3  | test1 | 10:30 |    0   |
| 4  | test2 | 10:31 |    1   |
| 5  | test3 | 10:25 |    0   |
```

Таблица логов, строк около миллиона +- Необходимо посчитать количество переходов статусов, именно сколько было за сутки переходов от состояния 1 в состояние 0 и наоборот. Итоговая таблица должна быть вида

```
| alias | Переходов |
| test1 |    15     |
| test2 |     0     |
```

На данный момент делаю просто, дергаю из базы по алиасу все статусы и в цикле сравниваю изменялось ли значение и если да увеличиваю счетчик на 1. Хотелось бы понять можно ли это сделать одним запросом к БД чтобы получить ВСЁ сразу и приджойнить результирующую таблицу к другой.

Comment: Укажите версию MySQL. *можно ли это сделать* Да, можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чисто для поржать (впрочем, работать будет):

```
SELECT alias, 2 * LENGTH(history) - LENGTH(REPLACE(history, '01', '-') - LENGTH(REPLACE(history, '10', '-') changes
FROM ( SELECT alias, GROUP_CONCAT(status ORDER BY time SEPARATOR '') history
       FROM datatable
       GROUP BY alias
     ) subquery
```

ПО этой технологии переходы 0->1 и 1->0 можно посчитать и отдельно, буде надо...

Comment: Спасибо, понял принцип и все получилось, но почему "чисто поржать"? Так никто не делает или есть какие то подводные камни?

Comment: *почему "чисто поржать"?* Да уж больно все эти строковые заморочки по ресурсам прожорливые. По уму это всё надо реализовывать на переменных при соотв. сортировке - но мне лично тупо лень.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы каждый раз когда вы меняете статус не плюсовать единицу в другую таблицу. Например:

```
UPDATE table1 SET status = 1 WHERE alias = 'test1';
UPDATE table2 SET count = count + 1 WHERE alias = 'test1';

UPDATE table1 SET status = 0 WHERE alias = 'test1';
UPDATE table2 SET count = count + 1 WHERE alias = 'test1';
```

И после сделать выборку и получить в результате сколько раз менялся статус

`SELECT count FROM table2 WHERE alias = 'test1';`

Comment: Ненадёжно. И вообще неприменимо, если данные могут заноситься постфактум.

Comment: почему не надежно?

Comment: Любой сбой - и кранты статистике...

Comment: в таблице логов - около миллиона записей,  один сбой +- одна запись из миллиона, не очень то на статистику повлияют, но даже если нужны точные данные то можно заключить в транзакцию.

Comment: ну это автору решать - важно или нет. А с учётом того, что лимон записей - для всех алиасов, да не за один день, такие ошибки могут запросто оказаться критичными...